# Calling MotionEvent ACTION_DOWN in between the Thread is asleep

Tags: android, multithreading, motionevent

I have a canvas screen in which i am scribbling with free hand . What i am trying to do is that when the user lifts up his finger after scribbling something `ACTION_UP` event will be called . 
My requirement is to know that the user has done his scribbling ,after he is done scribbling i will take my action .

To acheive this in the `ACTION_UP` event,i am making a new thread to sleep for 3 second ,but i want that when the thread is asleep and during that 3 second if the user starts to scribble again on the screen then i want to call `ACTION_DOWN` event .

I am not getting any way to do this . Code is mentioned below .
Please help .

```
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

     thread = new Thread() {
                    int wait = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        super.run();
                        while (wait < 3000) {
                            try {
                                sleep(100);
                                wait += 100;

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        try {
                            pointerUp();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                };
                thread.start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But why cant you set up a global boolean flag for that? befroe nd after the thread asleep , check if an action up is happend, if so, set it true. Then based in the value of the flag, you can code else.